# data from csv file with encoding different from utf-8 is written to mysql with what encoding?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, character-encoding

I have csv file upload and the file can be with UTF-8 encoding or something else like KOI8-R. My question is when I say:

```
  File.new  @path, "r:#{encoding}"                 
  result = CSV.read(@uploaded_file,  { :headers => true,:encoding => encoding })
```

encoding is KOI8-R
and I write the result to mysql does Rails 3 automatically converts the values from KOI8-R to UTF-8?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think not Rails converts the encoding , but your database does. My advice is to check database settings for the encodings.